# How to apply css to ngx-datatable checked row

Tags: css, angular, ngx-datatable

I tried

```
.datatable-body-row:checked .datatable-row-group {
  background-color: #22e26c !important;
}
```

Nothing happens, while for hover it works, like this.

```
.datatable-body-row:hover .datatable-row-group {
  background-color: #abd4ee !important;
}
```

How can I make the row that is checked have custom color?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `.datatable-body-row.active` ?

If you looking at their site you can select a row and look into dev tools to search for applied styles.

https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#single-selection

Comment: Yes I did, the result is now they all are custom color regardless of the checkbox. That's the tricky party I think. Because checked is different value binding then active I think, thats why thing gets messy for me.

Comment: @AkiZukiLennDan you provide a small stackblitz with your code and styles?

Comment: not yet, I tried 
`.datatable-body-row ,.row-checkbox:checked {
  background-color: green !important;
}`
all green, regardness `row-checkbox` input element is checked or not. Just an update that may help.

Comment: Its also a multi checkbox selection

Comment: `input:checked{
  background-color: green !important;
}` doesn't worked

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz with your table and your custom elements actions you used. Ngx-datatable official site dosent provide an example with checkboxes and row selection